# Remove Paste option from MenuItems in iOS 16

Tags: swift, contextmenu, ios16

I have a custom menu options written in

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool { }
```

in iOS 16 I see now a Paste option in the context option. I tried to hide it via

```
if action.description == "paste:" { return false } //FAILED


return action != #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) // FAILED
```

but did not help. I see Paste option now everywhere.
How to get rid of it ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `paste` option from the default context menu, use this:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if action != #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help. Paste context menu is still present.... Fun fact that after your code sample "Cut" option has been added :D

Comment: @YaroslavDukal its not happening at my end though, could you post a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: the issue i found is connected to  override func paste method. If comment it out all good. But i need that method to detect pasted images. Any ideas how i can fix that?